# Why is Django looking for templates in the wrong directory?

Tags: django, django-templates

Where does django look for Templates by default?

I thought by default django looks for templates in `myApp/templates/myApp/` folder but in my case django is looking for templates in `myApp/templates/` folder.

I am unable to force django to look cahnge the directory of templates. Here is the structure of my directory.
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71y3A.png)

I worked on other projects but those worked fine. I was wondering if the documentation has changed in django 4.2.1

Here are the codes:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'school'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

school/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

django_project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('school.urls')),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Comment: Please update folder structure screenshot so the path we're talking about can be seen. Currently folders are collapsed. And show `views.home` code. If you get some error message - please post this error traceback.

Comment: I have added my views.py code. And the picture link of the directory structure is given in the link `Directory Structure` above. [Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TajOc.png)

Comment: do you have a 'school' folder inside of "/school/templates"? Put your templates for the school app inside of '/school/templates/school/'

Comment: Yes I have `school` folder in `/school/templates`. The directory is `/school/templates/school` where all my templates are. Here is the updated screenshot link [Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71y3A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view it should be

```
return render(request, 'school/home.html')
```

prefixed with the app/subfolder name which is under `app/templates/` directory.

Related [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) part:

> Within the templates directory you have just created, create another directory called polls, and within that create a file called **index.html**. In other words, your template should be at **polls/templates/polls/index.html**. Because of how the app_directories template loader works as described above, *you can refer to this template within Django as* **polls/index.html**.

Comment: I am sorry for the trouble. It worked
Thank you